# Menu buttons in tvOS SpriteKit app

Tags: ios, swift, button, sprite-kit, tvos

I have a problem with getting know how to approach making menu buttons in tvOS manner. I am aware about the new way how the UIKit buttons are focused, but the navigation between them is done behind the scenes. In SpriteKit there is no FocusEngine support, so here's my question, could you please guys give a hint or a code snippet (preferable swift) how to create a SKSpriteNode button and how to implement it so it can behave as a button?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this but it works for me and my tvOS game. I have used gesture recognizer and I use swipe right and left to change my SKSpriteNode texture. That creates effect of selected/deselected buttons. Than I simply use variable buttonSelected which is of type bool and I update it whenever button texture is changed. Than I use this variable to decide which action should be executed after click on the remote. That is done with simple if statement in the buttonAction function. I hope this will help you. I am still quite new to swift so I hope I described it clearly.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button.png")
var buttonSelected = false

var button2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button2.png")
var button2Selected = false

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    button.position = CGPoint(x: 900, y:100)
    self.addChild(button)

    button2.position = CGPoint(x: 1700, y:100)
    self.addChild(button2)

    // gesture recognizer

    let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameOverScene.swipedRight(_:)))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameOverScene.swipedLeft(_:)))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let tapGeneralSelection = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapGeneralSelection.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.buttonAction))
    tapGeneralSelection.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber (integer: UIPressType.Select.rawValue)]
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGeneralSelection)
}

func swipedRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    let buttonTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "button2Selected.png")
    button2.runAction(SKAction.setTexture(buttonTexture1))
    button2Selected = true

    let buttonTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "button.png")
    button.runAction(SKAction.setTexture(buttonTexture2))
    buttonSelected = false
}

func swipedLeft(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    let buttonTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "buttonSelected.png")
    button.runAction(SKAction.setTexture(buttonTexture1))
    buttonSelected = true

    let buttonTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "button2.png")
    button2.runAction(SKAction.setTexture(buttonTexture2))
    button2Selected = false
}

func buttonAction() {

    if( buttonSelected == true) {
        // do something after button is pressed
    } else if (button2Selected == true) {
       // do something after button2 is pressed
  }
}
```

}